# Partial derivatives for $\|x\|^2 = x_1^2+\dots+ x_n^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

> Let $f: \mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $x \mapsto \|x\|^2 = x_1^2+\dots+ x_n^2\:$ for $n>2.$ Find the partial derivatives at $x$ and determine the derivative at $x$.

This seems to be just a problem dealing with the chain rule for partial derivatives. However, I got pretty confused since I would have to apply it $n$ times, how would this go?

For the second part if I just denote $x=x_0$ I would get $$f(x)-f(x_0) = \nabla f(x_0)\cdot (x-x_0)+ \|(x-x_0)\|\varepsilon(x_0-x)$$
for the derivative.

Comment: There is no chain rule here. All you have to use in order to find the partial derivatives is that the derivative of $x^2$ is $2x$.

Comment: Ah obviously! The gradient would then be $(2x_1, \dots , 2x_n)$? I would need this for the derivative.

Comment: What you call the derivative is the differential of the function?

Comment: Might I be confusing the terms? This is what we use on our class currently for the generalisation of the derivative.

Comment: Why not first find the derivative using the product rule: $$d_pf(x)=\langle p,x\rangle+\langle x,p\rangle=2\langle p,x\rangle$$ and then substitute $e_k=(0,\dots,1,\dots,0)$ to get the partial derivative?

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x_1,\dots,x_n) = x_1^2+\dots+x_n^2 \implies \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_k} = 2x_k$$

All the terms different from $x_k^2$ are fixed so they become $0$ differentiating.

Answer (score 0):

$\nabla f=(2x_1,\dots,2x_n)$.  The $i$th partial is $\partial f/\partial x_i=2x_i$.

So, at $x_0$, we get $\nabla f(x_0)=2x_0$.